# python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'createSession

Tags: python, attributeerror

The piece of code looks like this which is a python script

I think this section is where the error creeps in

```
def getSessionManagementMBean(sessionName):
    SessionMBean = findService("SessionManagement", "com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.SessionManagementMBean")
    SessionMBean.createSession(sessionName)
    return SessionMBean
```

and when we run the script, we run into this error

```
  File "/var/cache/chef/weblogic/managed/config-setup/smtpConfig/import.py", line 190, in getSessionManagementMBean
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'createSession
```

I was thinking to replace the above code with this

```
def getSessionManagementMBean(sessionName):
    SessionMBean = findService("SessionManagement", "com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.SessionManagementMBean")
    Variable = SessionMBean.createSession(sessionName)
    print Variable
    return Variable
```

Any solutions or comments welcome please

Comment: The `findService()` call returned `None`. You could test for that: `if SessionMBean is not None: SessionMBean.createSession(sessionName)`. But you may need to figure out why the `findService()` call failed in the first place.

Comment: Your proposed change won't fix the exception, because the exception is caused by `SessionMBean` referring to `None` and that object has no `.createSession()` method.

Comment: yeah, thats true, i wanted to check if the print of that variable after it was changed would return a value or not, But thanks for the comment

Comment: Since the `None.createSession()` method doesn't exist, the exception is raised before any assignment is made to `Variable`, and your `print` statement is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getSessionManagementMBean(sessionName):
    SessionMBean = findService("SessionManagement",
                   "com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.SessionManagementMBean")
    if SessionMBean: # check SessionMBean is not 'None'
        SessionMBean.createSession(sessionName)
        return SessionMBean
    # if SessionMBean is 'None' or 0 then raise your own exception 
    raise Exception("Something happened with SessionMBean")
```

Comment: This just raises a different exception; it's not that different from just letting the the original AttributeError propagate.

Comment: @chepner True, but personally I'd find that message a little more understandable rather than the typical "I did something with a null somewhere I shouldn't."

Comment: This way, if you create your own exception, then you catch it and handle it accordingly, instead of just trying to catch a `AttributeError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a method (findService) that it does not return a correct Object or this method assign a result but it does not return an object.
Check if SessionMBean is your correct object or is None.